# Dependency on hugepages - systemd

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab

I have a service running on Bionic (18.04.5), which requires that `/mnt/huge` be mounted.
This service runs most often, but in some rare cases it fails and I see that the `hugetlbfs`
is not mounted on the system.
Do I have to add a line like

```
Requires=mnt-huge.mount
```

To my unit file ? I see that there is already:

```
hugetlbfs /mnt/huge hugetlbfs defaults 0 0
```

in `/etc/fstab`